# Hiding specific totals in text table

Tags: tableau-api

I have a text table similar to below

[image]

Is there any way to hide the $0.0M totals? I don't want to remove them from the calculation, I just want to perform something like an alias on the totals to blank them out.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: See if it helps https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C64BU/hide-zero-or-null-values, else please tell

Comment: Does this do it? https://tarsolutions.co.uk/blog/tableau-format-zero-values/

Comment: Sorry for just now responding, but yes! The easiest option was utilizing the custom formatting.